# Canvas response to clicks

Tags: canvas, click, game-engine

I have a canvas where image drawing is refreshed according to a FPS.

At each refresh, a same image is drawn in canvas. 
But when I click in this image to execute a function, sometime the canvas doesn't react, sometime the canvas react with some delay.

But I want the canvas executes the function immediately  when I click in the image.

So what is the problem ? the FPS ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably not the FPS, but we can't investigate without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you can provide a snippet or a working example via jsFiddle we can help you out. But jugding by your problem I would state it is most probably your click event

Comment: I found the problem : if I click the image between two refreshs, the canvas doesn't react.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using this as your click reaction:

```
var canvas = ...
var ctx = ...
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", getPosition, false)
function getPosition(event) {
x = event.x;
y = event.y;
x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
y -= canvas.offsetTop;

// Now put code to describe specifically where to click

if (x < 500 && x > 200 && y < 900 && y > 500) {
// Code code code...
}

}
```

I hope this helped :)